# mod_rewrite not working for query string redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have one rewrite rule for pretty urls, which is working fine.  I tried adding in a second, and it's giving me problems:

```
# redirect /?p=xyz to /xyz
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING}         ^p=(.*)$
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$                   /index.php/%1 [L]

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond                     $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$  [NC]
RewriteCond                     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond                     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule                     ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The second one is working fine, but the first one is giving me internal server error.  Basically I want anything in ?p=* to go to /index.php/*

[Edit] Just to clarify, I need http://domain.com/?p=test to be equivalent to http://domain.com/test/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `domain.com/test`  to  `domain.com/?p=test`

Try this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !p=   [NC]
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/?   /?p=$1 [L,NC]
```

#### OPTION:

In case it is the opposite:
`domain.com/?p=test` to `domain.com/test/index.php`

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=([^/]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule  .*   /%1/index.php?   [L,NC]
```

Remove `index.php` in case it is not needed, like this:

```
RewriteRule  .*   /%1/?    [L,NC]
```

Comment: I want the value of p to be passed in the URL.  Wouldn't your rewrite rules just pass the query string along as a query string still?

Comment: It is passed. Just test my answer please and once you see the result I will be glad to modify it, if needed.

Comment: I just tried it, and it did not work.  Just to clarify, I need http://domain.com/?p=test to be the equivalent of http://domain.com/test/

Comment: Okay. That's quite different from what I understood from your question. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure about the mapping direction so added one option and made several modifications to it. Please make sure you are testing the current version.